# Reiniciar comando para ver se houve alteração no valor

Tags: php, javascript

Olá, criei uma função para verificar quantos cupons o usuário tem, gostaria de ter um botão [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui] que executasse a função novamente. Essa é a função:

```
<?php co(); $Cupons=VerificaCupons(); echo''.$Cupons.'  Cupons'; qc(); ?>
```

Deve funcionar apenas como um botão de *reload* para a função e, se houver alteração no valor, não muda nada, pois o usuário só deseja saber quantos cupons ele tem e se foi adicionado ou diminuído.

Podem me ajudar?

Comment: A solução precisa ser só em JavaScript ou em jQuery está bom para você?

Comment: Essa pergunta está sendo discutida no [meta](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/5184/tag-adicionada-sem-relacao-com-questao) @Miguel

Comment: Obagdo @Florida. Entendi o problema